# Conditional expectation 2 tasks

Tags: probability-theory

I am having problems with two tasks.

1. Let $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ , $P$ be Lebesgue Measure.

Let $X(x,y)=x$ , $Y(x,y)=y$

find $E [f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]$ if $f(x,y)=xy$ , $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$

2. Let $\Omega=[0,1], P=dx$. Find $E[X|Y]$ if $X(x)={x}^2$ and $Y(x)=1-|2x-1|$

So in first task :

$$E[f(x,y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[XY|\sigma(X)]=X \cdot E[Y|\sigma(X)]$$ because $X$ is measurable by $\sigma(X)$, but what with $E[Y|\sigma(X)]$ ? $Y$ is continuous and I can't group $\sigma(X)$ into finite number of sets, but I think that $\sigma(X)$ is generating  Borel Sets in   $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $Y$ is measurable by $\sigma(X)$ and that   implies that $E[Y|\sigma(X)]=Y$ but it's only my guessing.

And in the second tasks I need to find density function of random vector $(X,Y)$ but I don't know if $X,Y$ are independent, and I have no idea how to find the density. Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 1):

1. The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent because for all Borel subset $A,B$ of $[0,1]$, $$\Pr(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})=\Pr\{(x,y)\in\Omega, x\in A, y\in B\}=\Pr\{X\in A\}\Pr\{Y\in B\}.$$
2. Observe that the function $Y$ is symmetric at $1/2$, or in order words, $Y(1-x)=Y(x)$ hence $\sigma(Y)=\{B\subset [0,1], B=1-B\}$ where $1-B=\{1-b,b\in B\}$. Let $B$ be an element of $\sigma(Y)$. Then 
   $$
   \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\mathbf 1_B(x)dx=\int_{[0,1/2]} f(x)\mathbf 1_B(x)dx
   +\int_{[1/2,1]} f(x)\mathbf 1_B(x)dx
   $$
   and doing the substitution $u=1-x$ in the second integral gives 
   $$
   \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\mathbf 1_B(x)dx=\int_{[0,1/2]} f(u)\mathbf 1_B(u)du
   +\int_{[0,1/2]} f(1-u)\mathbf 1_B(u)du
   =\int_{[0,1/2]} \left(f(u)+f(1-u)\right)\mathbf 1_B(u)du
   $$
   which can be rewritten as 
   $$
   \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\mathbf 1_B(x)dx 
   =\int_{[0,1]} \frac{f(u)+f(1-u)}2\mathbf 1_B(u)du.
   $$

Comment: Is  f(u) a density function of $(X,Y)$, what is function formula of f(u)?

Comment: In 2, a way to compute $\mathbb E\left[X\mid \right]$ is presented where $X(x)=f(x)$ and $Y(x)=1-|2x-1|$, which is a more general setting than that of the initial question.

Comment: Thank you for help :)